# Prove that **PTIME** has no complete problems with respect to linear-time reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

> Prove that **PTIME** has no complete problems with respect to
>   linear-time reductions.

I know that **PTIME** means all these problems that we can solve them in polynomial time. I suppose that I should use here time hierarchy theorem - I know it.

However, I have no idea how to solve it. I am beginner at this subject so I ask for explanation for dummy :)

Comment: Cross-posted, and answered on [Math.SE]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2196898/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, even though it is on-topic here, because it was cross-posted elsewhere.